# terraform does not apply standard attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Standard attributes like `gender`, `birthdate` are not visible in AWS Cognito, only email exists

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user-pool" {
  name = "user-pool-${terraform.workspace}"

  alias_attributes = ["email"]
  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]

  mfa_configuration = "OFF"

  schema {
    name = "email"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = false
    required = true

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
    }
  }

  schema {
    name = "gender"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = false
    required = false

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
    }
  }

  schema {
    name = "birthdate"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    required = false
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = true

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
    }
  }

  password_policy {
    minimum_length = "8"
    require_lowercase = false
    require_numbers = false
    require_symbols = false
    require_uppercase = false
  }
}
```

I've tried deleting users pool manually but it still the same
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43336228/105615040-be75c480-5dcd-11eb-8ce0-d9227bac1b26.png

Only `email` has checkbox while `birthdate` and `gender` does not

```
  schema = [{
    name = "gender"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = false
    required = false

    string_attribute_constraints = {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
    }
  }, {
    name = "birthdate"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    required = false
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = true

    string_attribute_constraints = {
    min_length = 1
    max_length = 2048
    }
  }]
```

Above code does not work aswell.
I'm getting error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on cognito.tf line 9, in resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user-pool":
   9:   schema = [{
```

Answer (score 3):

You have `birthday` and `gender` as **not required**. So the screenshot is correct, as it only indicates required attributes. To make them required, and thus, show in the attributes list you have to do:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user-pool" {
  name = "user-pool-${terraform.workspace}"

  alias_attributes = ["email"]
  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]

  mfa_configuration = "OFF"

  schema {
    name = "email"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = false
    required = true

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
    }
  }

  schema {
    name = "gender"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = false
    required = true

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
    }
  }

  schema {
    name = "birthdate"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    required = true
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable = true

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
    }
  }

  password_policy {
    minimum_length = "8"
    require_lowercase = false
    require_numbers = false
    require_symbols = false
    require_uppercase = false
  }
}
```